I encountered an error about splashscreen：E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: wmshell.splashscreen
09-24 03:57:26.301  1479  1656 I input_interaction: Interaction with: 2b24e54 Splash Screen com.chaozh.iReaderFree (server), PointerEventDispatcher0 (server),  09-24 03:57:26.306  1479  2910 D MediaSessionService: Sending KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=302575776000000, downTime=302575776000000, deviceId=-1, source=0x101, displayId=-1 } to com.freeme.cloud.theme/com.freeme.cloud.theme (userId=0) 09-24 03:57:26.310  1479 22067 D WindowManager: interceptKeyTq keycode=90 interactive=true keyguardActive=false policyFlags=2b000000 09-24 03:57:26.311  1818  1873 E InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event. 09-24 03:57:26.311  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: packageName does not belong to the calling uid; pkg=com.chaozh.iReaderFree, uid=10080 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3061) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3041) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3024) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2966) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.media.session.ISessionManager$Stub$Proxy.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(ISessionManager.java:728) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.media.session.MediaSessionManager.dispatchMediaKeyEventInternal(MediaSessionManager.java:617) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.media.session.MediaSessionManager.dispatchMediaKeyEventAsSystemService(MediaSessionManager.java:610) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneFallbackEventHandler.handleMediaKeyEvent(PhoneFallbackEventHandler.java:322) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneFallbackEventHandler.onKeyDown(PhoneFallbackEventHandler.java:108) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneFallbackEventHandler.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneFallbackEventHandler.java:74) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7288) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:7103) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6517) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6574) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6540) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6705) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6548) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6762) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6521) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6574) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6540) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6548) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6521) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6574) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6540) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6705) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6548) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6762) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6521) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6574) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6540) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6548) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6521) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6574) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6540) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6705) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6548) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6762) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6521) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9608) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:9555) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9510) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9765) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:267) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:162) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI: Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace: 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at com.android.server.media.MediaServerUtils.enforcePackageName(MediaServerUtils.java:79) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at com.android.server.media.MediaSessionService.tempAllowlistTargetPkgIfPossible(MediaSessionService.java:545) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at com.android.server.media.MediaSessionRecord$SessionCb.sendMediaButton(MediaSessionRecord.java:1293) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at com.android.server.media.MediaSessionRecord.sendMediaButton(MediaSessionRecord.java:510) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at com.android.server.media.MediaSessionService$SessionManagerImpl.dispatchMediaKeyEventLocked(MediaSessionService.java:2335) 09-24 03:57:26.312  1818  1873 E MessageQueue-JNI:  09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: wmshell.splashscreen 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.systemui, PID: 1818 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: packageName does not belong to the calling uid; pkg=com.chaozh.iReaderFree, uid=10080 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3061) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3041) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3024) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2966) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.media.session.ISessionManager$Stub$Proxy.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(ISessionManager.java:728) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.media.session.MediaSessionManager.dispatchMediaKeyEventInternal(MediaSessionManager.java:617) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.media.session.MediaSessionManager.dispatchMediaKeyEventAsSystemService(MediaSessionManager.java:610) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneFallbackEventHandler.handleMediaKeyEvent(PhoneFallbackEventHandler.java:322) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneFallbackEventHandler.onKeyDown(PhoneFallbackEventHandler.java:108) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneFallbackEventHandler.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneFallbackEventHandler.java:74) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7288) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:7103) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6517) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6574) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6540) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6705) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6548) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6762) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6521) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6574) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6540) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6548) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6521) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6574) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6540) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6705) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6548) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6762) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6521) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6574) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6540) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6548) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6521) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6574) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6540) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6705) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6548) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6762) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6521) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9608) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:9555) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9510) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9765) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:267) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:162) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace: 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.server.media.MediaServerUtils.enforcePackageName(MediaServerUtils.java:79) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.server.media.MediaSessionService.tempAllowlistTargetPkgIfPossible(MediaSessionService.java:545) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.server.media.MediaSessionRecord$SessionCb.sendMediaButton(MediaSessionRecord.java:1293) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.server.media.MediaSessionRecord.sendMediaButton(MediaSessionRecord.java:510) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.server.media.MediaSessionService$SessionManagerImpl.dispatchMediaKeyEventLocked(MediaSessionService.java:2335) 09-24 03:57:26.313  1818  1873 E AndroidRuntime:  09-24 03:57:26.316 26312 30097 I dumpstate: Parsed the node: 21284
I need help, can anyone tell me what the problem is?
